# How does the implicit cast in BigInteger.Equals(Object obj) work?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I was looking at the documentation for BigInteger and ran across the following in the `BigInteger.Equals(Object obj)` method:

*If the obj parameter is not a BigInteger value, but it is a data type for which an implicit conversion is defined, the Equals(Object) method converts obj to a BigInteger value before it performs the comparison.*

I then started wondering how I would go about doing this, given that converting from the object would require an explicit cast. The best way I came up with is as follows:

```
Type type = obj.GetType()
if(type == typeof(byte))
{
  byte b = (byte)obj;
  return Equals(b);
}
if(type == typeof(short))
{
  short s = (short)obj;
  return Equals(s);
}
//Continue for all types that can be implicitly cast to BigInteger.
```

It just seems to me that there's an easier way to do this that I'm missing. So what other methods are there to do an implicit conversion, given that I'm starting with an object?

Comment: Using Reflector just gives `return obj != null && obj is BigInteger && this.Equals((BigInteger)obj);`.

Comment: I'm seeing `return ((obj is BigInteger) && this.Equals((BigInteger) obj));`

Comment: @asawyer I actually use ILSpy so maybe that's the difference.

Comment: Ok. I've just tried some code and determined that `BigInteger.Equals(Object obj)` returns false when I test for equality with an integer casted to an object. I feel silly for not trying that before asking the question, but I'm going to wait to see what sort of answers I get, regardless of the fact that `BigInteger.Equals(Object obj)` appears to act differently than its documentation.

Comment: @JoelRondeau Note that there is no *implicit* conversion from int to `BigInteger`.  Therefore `obj is BigInteger` will return false in that case.  If, however, you create your own class that is a subclass of `BigInteger` there will be an implicit conversion and you could use it.

Comment: @Servy - Here's the documentation for the implicit conversion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268348(v=vs.100)

Comment: @Servy [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx) states: Note that the is operator only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, are not considered by the is operator.

Comment: Weird. My first comment was based on `System.Numeric.BigInteger` (no `s`!) and I didn't notice.

Comment: @JoelRondeau The `implicit` keyword doesn't create a true implicit conversion between the two types (it is misleading that way).  It is an entirely compile time construct.  If you assign a variable of one type to another, and there is an implicit conversion, the compiler will wrap the expression in a call to the static conversion method.  At runtime the CLR has no knowledge of any user defined implicit conversions.  There is no way for it to know that one exists, or to find the method if it were to exist.  `implicit` really just fakes an `implicit` conversion rather than *really* making one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation from ILSpy:

```
return obj is BigInteger && this.Equals((BigInteger)obj);
```

At the very least the documentation could be considered misleading in its wording. What it means is `BigInteger` or *anything that derives from it* will have an implicit cast to `BigInteger` and will thus be cast to a `BigInteger` for the purposes of testing equality.

The current definition of `struct` will mean that nothing can derive from `BigInteger`, so the documentation is actually a little pointless in that statement.

It is possible you are getting confused with the user-defined `implicit` operator, which is what will have been used to allow `int`, `short`, et al to be stored in `BigInteger` "implicitly" in code:

```
BigInteger b = 1;
```

Comment: Under what conditions would a type have an implicit conversion to `BigInteger` where `obj is BigInteger` would return false?

Comment: @Servy The `implicit` operator does not factor into the behaviour of the `is` operator (at least on my test code). So, any integer type that can go into `BigInteger` would be a condition under which `obj is BigInteger` returns false, other than `BigInteger` itself or anything in the inheritance chain (which won't be possible as it is a struct).

Comment: That's because the `implicit` operator doesn't actually create a "real" implicit conversion.  It is only a compile time construct.  At runtime user created `implicit` methods have no bearing.  "real" implicit conversions are essentially any time for which the code shown here will work (i.e. a class that is a subclass of `BigInteger`).

Comment: @Servy Indeed, which again makes no sense as `BigInteger` is a struct.

Comment: The point is that the documentation isn't wrong.  I would agree it may very well be misleading, but it is technically correct.  My guess is that the documentation text for this `Equals` method is just copy-pasted around to a lot of different places (because it will almost always be technically correct) without thought to as to whether the given type will actually have any other type that have implicit conversions.

Comment: In both this answer and @Servy's comment to the original question, "derived from BigInteger" is mentioned. However, you can't actually derive from BigInteger. I would agree with Servy though, that the documentation is probably copy-pasted, so given a class that you can derive from, it is more accurate.

Comment: @JoelRondeau I actually mention that it cannot happen because `BigInteger` is defined as `struct`. I'll amend it to be more explicit.

Comment: @JoelRondeau The documentation is technically correct in that if there is an implicit conversion to `BigInteger` that conversion will be made.  There just happens to not be any types, nor the ability to make any types, that will ever have such a conversion.

Comment: @Servy I've been looking around the documentation, and figured I'd start with things where I know there are implicit conversions. Int32 and Int16, for example. Their `Equals(Object obj)` documentation doesn't make the same claim (and testing shows that the comparison fails). Right now, I haven't found any other place where Equals(Object obj) has similar documentation (well, except Complex, which I expected to). I'm thinking this isn't actually a copy-paste thing. I do otherwise tend to agree with your assessment.

Comment: @JoelRondeau Well, searching on Google for that term (without `BigInteger` returns the page for BigInteger, Complex, and then this page, in that order, followed by a number of pages that don't actually contain the full phrase.  I guess my guess of copy/paste is probably not the case after all.